# I get nil on a variable when running app on iPad3 but not on simulator. Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my 1st app I have a function that posts to Firebase as `[String:String]` dictionary, and in Firebase I see all values posted are `String`. In my 2nd app I have a function that reads that node and retrieves as `[String:String]`also, but in the snapshot print two of the values, `Booking Date`and `Booking Id` look like `Int`. I than actually make them `Int` like I need them to be and when I run my 2nd app on simulator `iOS 12.1` it't all good and works as expected, but when I run it on my iPad 3 `iOS 9.3.5` app crashes because`let bookingId = Int(value["Booking Id"]!)` is nil, but that doesn't happen with`let bookingDate = Int(value["Booking Date"]!)`. Looks like iPad doesn't
like converting more than one value.
Do you see any solution to this?
Here is the function:

```
func getMyBookings() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Shops").child("Workshop Bookings").queryOrdered(byChild: "Shop Name").queryEqual(toValue: "Spezial Cycle").observe(.value)  { (snapshot) in

        //        ref.child("Continent").child("Europe").child("Country").child("Italy").child("Region").child("Emilia-Romagna").child("City").child("Bologna").child("Shops").child("Workshop Bookings").queryOrdered(byChild: "Shop Name").queryEqual(toValue: "Spezial Cycle").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: [String:String]] {

            for (_, value) in
                data{
                    let bookingDate = Int(value["Booking Date"]!)!
                    //                        let bookingDate = value["Booking Date"]!
                    print("bookingDate is: \(String(describing: bookingDate))")
                    let bookingStart = value["Booking Start"]
                    let bookingEnd = value["Booking End"]
                    let customerName = value["User Name"]
                    let bookingId = Int(value["Booking Id"]!)!
                    print("bookingId is :\(String(describing: bookingId))")
                    let booking: (bookingDate: Int, bookingStart: String, bookingEnd: String, customerName: String, bookingId: Int) = (bookingDate!, bookingStart!, bookingEnd!, customerName!, bookingId: bookingId)
                    print("booking is: \(booking)")
                    self.bookingsArray.append(booking)
                    self.calculateBookedTimeSlots()
            }
            self.calculateBookedTimeSlots()
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                let actions: [UNNotificationAction] = [UNNotificationAction(identifier: "chiudi", title: "Chiudi", options: [.foreground])]
                Notifications.newTimeIntervalNotification(notificationType: "New booking", actions: actions, categoyIdentifier: "New Booking", title: "Nuova prenotazione", body: "Hai una nuova prenotazione", userInfo: [:], timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
            } else if #available(iOS 9.0, *){
                // Fallback on earlier versions

                Notifications.newTimeIntervalNotification(notificationType: "New booking", actions: [], categoyIdentifier: "New Booking", title: "Nuova prenotazione", body: "Hai una nuova prenotazione", userInfo: [:], timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
            }
        }
        //        })
    }
}
```

And this is the snapshot print showing both `Booking Date`and `Booking Id`looking like `Int`:

```
Snap (Workshop Bookings) {
    "-Lb4XzGtLtnBAgoPB6Ay" =     {
        "Booking Date" = 20190329;
        "Booking End" = "14:00";
        "Booking Id" = 201903291300;
        "Booking Start" = "13:00";
        "Shop Logo Url" = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fix-it-b4b00.appspot.com/o/Spezial%20Cycle%2FSpezial%20Cycle%20logo.png?alt=media&token=016cc976-ae8d-4c71-a77f-a899d661be20";
        "Shop Name" = "Spezial Cycle";
        "User Name" = "";
        "Works List" = "Revisione Generale, ";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your iPad 3 is still running on a 32 bit data bus, and the value 201903291300 is slightly too large to fit into that `Int32` (which is the `Int` implementation on 32 bit architecture).

You should try to use `Int64` instead of `Int`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it. I had to change quite a few of `Int`to `Int64`but it finally runs on the iPad.